# What is CSR indexing as a join optimization technique?

Tags: apache-spark, join, query-optimization, spark-graphx

The Spark Graphx paper mentions CSR indexing in the following context:

> GraphX recasts system optimizations developed in the context of graph
>   processing systems as join optimizations (e.g., CSR indexing, join
>   elimination, and join-site specification) and materialized view
>   maintenance (e.g., vertex mirroring and delta updates)

However when I googled for

```
CSR indexing join optimization
```

The results were related to

```
Corporate Social Responsibility.
```

Now I'm sure we are all for that ;)   However, i would be interested in info on the more tech related acronym and semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found it inside of a matrix operations paper: it is

> Compressed Sparse Row

Details:

> CSR permits indexed access to rows. Similar to COO, CSR storage
>   structure also consists of three sparse vectors, non-zero vector,
>   column vector and row vector. Index structure differs in the formation
>   of row vector. In CSR row vector consists of pointers to each row of
>   the matrix.

Comparison of Sparse Matrix Algorithms:

> http://ir.cs.georgetown.edu/publications/downloads/SCI-Journal-CameraReady-Goharian.pdf